# java library for legal move generation in chess

Tags: java, open-source, chess

I am looking for a an API to generate legal moves validation in chess, preferably in the Java language.

I could write my own but it would be a naive implementation, and it would be slow. So I need a working library allowing more or less the following operations:

```
Board board = new Board();
board.reset();
board.isMoveLegal(playerNum, fromSquare, toSquare);
board.inputMove(playerNum, fromSquare, toSquare);
```

What I want to avoid is having to browse a full chess game's code source with GUI, internet connectivity, or other functions than move generation. It would be a big waste of time for me and I'd rather spend a few hours to program my own move validator, no matter how slow. I also don't need any guidelines for writing my own library, as I have found plenty of which on the internet.

I'm asking this here because I have run several searches on google and didn't find what I was looking for. So it would be nice of you to point me out a link to such a working  code if you knew any. Thanks.

Comment: A couple of special cases aside, move validation in chess is pretty simple. What makes you think that "a naive implementation [...] would be slow"?

Comment: have you gone through the material here? http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/

Comment: @aix: it would be slowER, of that i'm sure, and i am running an internet server, so a difference of several CPU cycles has a meaning for me.

Comment: @prusswan: yes I have. It is quite vast and I didn't find anything but guidelines.

Comment: Your title mentions "generation", but your example code only does verification. Which one do you need? Generate some (or all) moves that are valid at the current time, or verify if a given move is valid? I'd guess that the latter is much easier.

Comment: You do need to be aware of the guidelines. It is not so much that your naive implementation will be slow, but because any implementation will place restrictions on other components like board representation, depending on what is the bigger objective

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Chesspresso<sup>TM</sup>](http://www.chesspresso.org/). Specifically [Move.isValid()](http://www.chesspresso.org/javadoc/chesspresso/move/Move.html#isValid%28%29).

Comment: I think you forgot the "TM" ;)

Comment: @basszero: Indeed! "My bad" TM

Comment: I can't make it work. There's no documentation or sample. For what I know, it could not work at all.

Comment: Maybe this helps you understand better how to use it: http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/an-attempt-at-ibms-ponder-this-feb-2010/

Comment: the link above in 'lucky toilet' is really good, as the library's documentation is horrid...